# Map Stops App from Loading

Tags: dictionary, windows-phone-8

I have referenced Windows.Phone.Controls and Windows.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.

When adding a map to the screen with via XML:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="Location">
            <maps:Map x:Name="Map" />
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

And adding the Capability in the App Manifest:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Deployment.Parts>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MAP" />
</Deployment.Parts>
```

Whenever I launch the application, it just stays on the Loading screen. I have added the Capability tag in the AppManifest because it fixed the "First chance exception".

Where am I going wrong? Can anyone see an obvious fix?

**Edit**
if I take the map off, the app loads perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add capabilities in `AppManifest.xml`. You add them in `WMAppManifest.xml`. Just open this file, it has a GUI window where you can tick the caps you want under `Capabilities` tab.

Comment: It would have been ideal for Microsoft to automatically check that box if a Map control has been added to the project.